# How do I seed data to Postgresql using GORM

Tags: linux, go, ubuntu, go-gorm, wsl-2

### Overview

I've just started learning golang and using GORM as the ORM but I can't seem to find documentation or how to create seed data and how to seed it. Hopefully someone here could help me with that

I have tried following this step by [Ilija Eftimov](https://ieftimov.com/posts/simple-golang-database-seeding-abstraction-gorm/) but it doesn't work or I don't know where I did wrong. Basically the function `seed.Seed` needs a return data which is `error` but the code he made doesn't have that.

### Environment

- OS=Ubuntu 20.04.4 (Windows 11 | WSL 2)
- Go=1.18.3
- IDE=VSCode
- ORM=GORM `github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.16

### Files

###### models/users.go

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    Email    string `gorm:"typevarchar(100);unique_index;not null"`
    Password string `json:"-"`
    UserType string
    Players  []Player
}
```

###### models/players.go

```
type Player struct {
    gorm.Model

    FirstName       string `gorm:"not null"`
    LastName        string
    Gender          string
    PrimaryPosition string
    Email           string
    UserID          int
    Team            string
}
```

### Expected response

I do hope there's either a `github` package that help us handle seed file and seeding it or a way to seed using `GORM`. From what I understand for now, we need to create seed files in:

- `pkg\seed` for `main seed function`
- `pkg\seeds` for `users` and `players` seed data